# Select second latest record for each group in the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, greatest-n-per-group

I have the data as below in my table in SQL Server database.

Query `select * from mytable order by UpdatedDate Desc` returns:

```
ID  COL1    UPDATED DATE
37  NULL    2018-06-25 18:20:50.210
37  NULL    2018-06-24 18:22:31.230
38  NULL    2018-04-03 14:16:47.953
38  NULL    2018-04-02 14:17:42.660
38  NULL    2018-04-01 14:17:55.963
44  NULL    2018-06-25 18:13:31.780
44  NULL    2018-06-23 18:13:44.020
44  NULL    2018-06-21 18:13:53.003
44  NULL    2018-06-20 18:14:01.490
```

What query will return me the result below, i.e second latest updated records

```
37  NULL    2018-06-24 18:22:31.230
38  NULL    2018-04-02 14:17:42.660
44  NULL    2018-06-23 18:13:44.020
```

Comment: Hello, did you try anything yet?

Answer (score 5):

Just find records with row number = 2. For *latest* records you need to order by date desc.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE DESC) AS rn
    FROM yourdata
) x
WHERE rn = 2
```